# How do I get a list of indexed Columns for a given Table

Tags: c#, sqlite

Given a SQLite database, I need to get a list of what columns in a given Table are indexed, and the sort order.  I need to do this from code (C#, though that shouldn't matter), so what I really need is a SQL statement, if one exists, that does this.

I know that I can do this:

`SELECT sql FROM SQLite_master WHERE type = 'index' AND tbl_name = 'MyTableName'`

And then manually parse the resulting SQL, but is there some metadata somewhere that I can just query that would give me something along these lines?

```
 ------------------------------------
|   name    | column     | direction |
 ------------------------------------
| idx_a     | ColA       | ASC       |
 ------------------------------------
| idx_a_b   | ColB, ColB | DESC      |
 ------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find any way to simply query the table meta and get the indo I wanted, so if anyone needs it, here's what I used.  Yes, Regex may have done a cleaner job, but you know the adage, if Regex can solve the problem, then now you have two problems.

```
public class SqlIndexInfo
{
    public string IndexName { get; set; }
    public string TableName { get; set; }
    public string[] Fields { get; set; }
    public bool IsAscending { get; set; }

    public bool IsComposite
    {
        get { return Fields.Length > 1; }
    }
}

public static class Extensions
{
    public static SqlIndexInfo ParseToIndexInfo(this string sql)
    {
        sql = sql.Trim();
        var info = new SqlIndexInfo();

        var i = sql.IndexOf("CREATE INDEX", 0, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
        if (i < 0) throw new ArgumentException("String is not valid CREATE INDEX SQL");
        var indexNameStart = i + "CREATE INDEX".Length + 1;

        i = sql.IndexOf(" ON ", 0, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
        if (i < 0) throw new ArgumentException("String is not valid CREATE INDEX SQL");
        var indexNameEnd = i;
        var tableNameStart = i + " ON ".Length;

        i = sql.IndexOf("(", 0, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
        if (i < 0) throw new ArgumentException("String is not valid CREATE INDEX SQL");
        var tableNameEnd = i;
        var fieldNamesStart = i + 1;

        i = sql.IndexOf(")", 0, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
        if (i < 0) throw new ArgumentException("String is not valid CREATE INDEX SQL");
        var fieldNamesEnd = i;
        var directionStart = i + 1;

        // TODO: strip brackets and/or single quotes?

        info.IndexName = sql.Substring(indexNameStart, indexNameEnd - indexNameStart).Trim();
        info.TableName = sql.Substring(tableNameStart, tableNameEnd - tableNameStart).Trim();
        info.Fields = (from f in sql.Substring(fieldNamesStart, fieldNamesEnd - fieldNamesStart).Split(',')
                      where !string.IsNullOrEmpty(f)
                      select f.Trim()).ToArray();

        if (directionStart >= sql.Length)
        {
            info.IsAscending = true;
        }
        else
        {
            info.IsAscending = sql.IndexOf("ASC", directionStart, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0;
        }

        return info;
    }
}
```

Comment: What a pain!  Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 33):

Use the `PRAGMA index_list(table-name);` and `PRAGMA index_info(index-name);` [extensions](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html).

Update: `PRAGMA schema.index_xinfo(index-name);` will return the sort order for key columns.

Comment: I see that I can divine the columns by getting an index list, then the info to derive the column, but what about sort order? I don't see anything that says if it's ASC or DESC

Comment: @ctacke Ah yes, it seems to be missing the sort order. Sigh.

Answer (score 14):

Add whatever conditions you want in where clause.  Fields are:

```
CREATE TABLE sqlite_master (
  type TEXT,
  name TEXT,
  tbl_name TEXT,
  rootpage INTEGER,
  sql TEXT
);
```

Pastable select...the important field to include for indexes is "sql".  Will not list primary keys defined in the create table statment.

```
select type, name, tbl_name, sql
FROM sqlite_master
WHERE type='index'
```

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT 
    m.tbl_name as table_name,
    il.name as index_name,
    ii.name as column_name,
    CASE il.origin when 'pk' then 1 else 0 END as is_primary_key,
    CASE il.[unique] when 1 then 0 else 1 END as non_unique,
    il.[unique] as is_unique,
    il.partial,
    il.seq as sequence_in_index
FROM sqlite_master AS m,
    pragma_index_list(m.name) AS il,
    pragma_index_info(il.name) AS ii
WHERE 
    m.type = 'table'
    and m.tbl_name = 'YOUR TABLENAME HERE'
GROUP BY
    m.tbl_name,
    il.name,
    ii.name,
    il.origin,
    il.partial,
    il.seq
ORDER BY 1,6
```

Answer (score 3):

That is literally how you do it: all the index metadata is available through the 'sqlite_master' table. See Q7 of the SQLite FAQ: http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q7

Comment: I'm not sure why somebody downvoted me, but let me restate this: the sqlite_master table is the native way to access this data via SQL. There is no other native mechanism.

Comment: But the sqlite_master table doesn't hold index name, columns and sort direction (outside of the SQL statement).  I'm trying to avoid the parsing.

Answer (score 1):

@neil briefly mentions [SQLite Pragma statements](https://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html) `PRAGMA INDEX_LIST['table_name']` and `PRAGMA INDEX_INFO['index_name']`. As per the documentation these exist both as SQLite commands as well as can be used in functions (i.e. `pragma_index_list(table_name)` and `pragma_index_info(index_name)`.

To understand this better, let's look at the following SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE Assets
(
    Asset_Id     INTEGER NOT NULL,
    Longitude    REAL    NOT NULL,
    Latitude     REAL    NOT NULL,
    Name         TEXT    NOT NULL,
    Installation REAL    NOT NULL,
    Constraint PK_Assets PRIMARY KEY (Asset_Id)
);
CREATE INDEX IX_Assets_Coordinate On Assets (Longitude, Latitude);
CREATE INDEX IX_Assets_Name On Assets (Name);
```

The following SQLite session demonstrates how to query the indexes:

```
.mode csv
sqlite> PRAGMA index_list('Assets');
seq,name,unique
0,IX_Assets_Name,0
1,IX_Assets_Coordinate,0
sqlite> PRAGMA index_info('IX_Assets_Name');
seqno,cid,name
0,3,Name
sqlite> PRAGMA index_info('IX_Assets_Coordinate');
seqno,cid,name
0,1,Longitude
1,2,Latitude
sqlite>
```

The interesting thing is the `PRAGMA` commands can be used like `SELECT` statements, so you will have no problems to run these commands in `C#`.

In [SQLite Pragma statements](https://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html) they have an interesting sample SQL statement for enumerating all indexes columns for all tables:

```
SELECT DISTINCT m.name || '.' || ii.name AS 'indexed-columns'
  FROM sqlite_master AS m,
       pragma_index_list(m.name) AS il,
       pragma_index_info(il.name) AS ii
 WHERE m.type = 'table'
 ORDER BY 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Optimizing from  @Steve Lloyd 's answer, order by `ii.seqno`

```
SELECT 
    m.tbl_name as table_name,
    il.name as index_name,
    ii.name as column_name,
    CASE il.origin when 'pk' then 1 else 0 END as is_primary_key,
    CASE il.[unique] when 1 then 0 else 1 END as non_unique,
    il.[unique] as is_unique,
    il.partial,
    il.seq as sequence_in_index,
    ii.seqno as sequence_in_column
FROM sqlite_master AS m,
    pragma_index_list(m.name) AS il,
    pragma_index_info(il.name) AS ii
WHERE 
    m.type = 'table'
    and m.tbl_name = 'YOUR TABLENAME HERE'
GROUP BY
    m.tbl_name,
    il.name,
    ii.name,
    il.origin,
    il.partial,
    il.seq
ORDER BY index_name,il.seq,ii.seqno
```