# Verify if an index exists in a Sqlite table

Tags: sqlite

I want to verify if an index exists for a SQL table. I'm trying this command (from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2689766/how-do-you-check-if-a-certain-index-exists-in-a-table)) :

```
SELECT * 
FROM sys.indexes 
WHERE name='YourIndexName' AND object_id = OBJECT_ID('Schema.YourTableName')
```

But I'm getting the error :

```
OperationalError: no such table: sys.indexes
```

with sqlite3 in Python.

Comment: You have a sqlite database. That link is an answer for microsoft "sql server". Those are two very different RDBMSs. [This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13426006/how-do-i-get-a-list-of-indexed-columns-for-a-given-table) would be more appropriate. [This page](https://database.guide/list-indexes-in-sqlite-database/) has a nice breakdown of that `USER_INDEXES` table mentioned in the other link's Q&A.

Comment: This might be of help: `select * from USER_INDEXES;`.

Comment: So what should I replace the "sys.indexes" with ? @Jnevil

Comment: https://sqlite.org/fileformat2.html#storage_of_the_sql_database_schema

Comment: Same error (but this time with USER_INDEXES) @Scott Hunter

Comment: @ScottHunter What is `USER_INDEXES` in sqlite?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT
   *
FROM
   sqlite_master
WHERE
   type= 'index' and tbl_name = 'your_table_name' and name = 'your_index_name';
```

You can use above query to verify index exist for a specific table and specific name.